# Returning the number of words in a list with a given number of vowels

Tags: python, function

Is there a way to edit this program so that it returns the number of words in a list with a given number of vowels?

I've tried but I can't seem to return the correct number and I don't know what my code is outputting.

(I'm a beginner)

```
def getNumWordsWithNVowels(wordList, num):
totwrd=0
x=0
ndx=0
while ndx<len(wordList):
    for i in wordList[ndx]:
        if(i=='a' or i=='e' or i=='i' or i=='o' or i=='u' or i=='A' or i=='E' or i=='I' or i=='O' or i=='U'):
            x+=1
        if x==num:
            totwrd+=1
        ndx+=1
return totwrd
```

print(getNumWordsWithNVowels(aList, 2))

This outputs "2" but it is supposed to output "5".

Comment: what code have you tried so far? What was the error?

Comment: it's not letting me paste the code???

Comment: You can do this with the NLTK package: https://www.nltk.org/

Comment: @TimothyWong Please use the `edit` function. format code by putting 4 spaces in front of each line.

Comment: Edit your question and paste your code inside. Remember to select your code and hit the `{}` button to format it.

Comment: It says "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut."

Comment: ok i'll try that

Comment: I got it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sum` function with a generator expression:

```
def getNumWordsWithNVowels(wordList, num):
    return sum(1 for w in wordList if sum(c in 'aeiou' for c in w.lower()) == num)
```

so that:

```
aList = ['hello', 'aloha', 'world', 'foo', 'bar']
print(getNumWordsWithNVowels(aList, 1))
print(getNumWordsWithNVowels(aList, 2))
print(getNumWordsWithNVowels(aList, 3))
```

outputs:

```
2 # world, bar
2 # hello, foo
1 # aloha
```

Comment: what does the return "sum" do?

Comment: `sum` is a built-in function that returns the total of the item values in a given sequence. Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) for more details.